# Sql Exception Incorrect syntax on adding temporary column to exsisting query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

Below query works fine.

```
SET @query = 'SELECT [UserId],[UserGroupId],
[UserName],[ColorID],[LastName],[FirstName],
[MiddleName],[OfficePhone],[MobilePhone],[Credential],
[PhyName],[User_Medi_License],[User_DEA],[User_NPI],
[User_phy_Roles],[User_Status],[UserHash],[LastLogIn],
[LoginIP],[LoginStatus],[FacilityID],
[Specialty_Taxonomy_Code],[TaxID_Type],[TaxID],
[EmailID],[isFlag],[IsDeleted],[AllowAppointment],
[BlockColorID],[BiilingPhyID],[UserImage],[ExternalPhyID],
[Nameprefix],[Namesuffix],[Group_NPI],[AppPhyID],
[DashboardOffice],[Street],[City],[State],[Zipcode],
[UseAsBillerInfo],[StateLicenseNum],[TaxIDnumber],
[UseTheme],[EmployeeID],[UserResAddress1],
[UserResAddress2],[UserResCity],[UserResState],
[UserResCountry],[UserSSN],[UserDOB],[userSpeciality],
[UserImageData] as UserImg,UserImageData,'' as tokenSER
FROM [dbo].[Z_UserMaster] WHERE [' + @Field + '] = ''' + @Value + ''''
```

ON adding temporary column {'' as tokenSER} It gives Incorrect syntax error in visual studio.

```
SET @query = 'SELECT [UserId],[UserGroupId],
[UserName],[ColorID],[LastName],[FirstName],
[MiddleName],[OfficePhone],[MobilePhone],[Credential],
[PhyName],[User_Medi_License],[User_DEA],[User_NPI],
[User_phy_Roles],[User_Status],[UserHash],[LastLogIn],
[LoginIP],[LoginStatus],[FacilityID],
[Specialty_Taxonomy_Code],[TaxID_Type],[TaxID],
[EmailID],[isFlag],[IsDeleted],[AllowAppointment],
[BlockColorID],[BiilingPhyID],[UserImage],[ExternalPhyID],
[Nameprefix],[Namesuffix],[Group_NPI],[AppPhyID],
[DashboardOffice],[Street],[City],[State],[Zipcode],
[UseAsBillerInfo],[StateLicenseNum],[TaxIDnumber],
[UseTheme],[EmployeeID],[UserResAddress1],
[UserResAddress2],[UserResCity],[UserResState],
[UserResCountry],[UserSSN],[UserDOB],[userSpeciality],
[UserImageData] as UserImg,UserImageData,'' as tokenSER, 
FROM [dbo].[Z_UserMaster] WHERE [' + @Field + '] = ''' + @Value + ''''
```

base={"Incorrect syntax near '27'.\r\nUnclosed quotation mark after the character string ''."} sqlexception

Answer (score 1):

In your second query you have invalid coma after `as tokenSER`. It is causing the `Incorrect syntax` error.

Comment: what should be the correct syntax to add temporary column.